# Possible Memory Leak with [NSString alloc]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I write plugins for a cross-platform application. My code depends almost entirely on the application's API for interacting with the outside world, which means my experience with the OS-level APIs is limited. But I do have a small amount of OS-specific code to accomplish goals that the application's API does not provide for. On the Mac side I have a number of code snippets like this one that changes the title of a Window:

First a utility function:

```c
NSString *GetNSStringFromUTF16 ( const utf16char * const str )
{
   size_t len = 0;
   while ( str[len] )
      len++;
   NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:str length:sizeof(*str)*len];
   NSString* retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
   [data release];
   return retVal;
}
```

Then later I set the window title like this:

```c
[myWind setTitle:GetNSStringFromUTF16(newTitleStr)];
```

I was running XCode Analyze and it flagged a number of "possible memory leaks" from calls to my `GetNSStringFromUTF16` function. But it did not flag this one. Is it a memory leak or not?

Comment: Use the static analyzer (shift+command+B or “Product” - “Analyze”). It’s very good at identifying these sorts of mistakes that plague manual reference count code.

Comment: FWIW, the rules about when `release`/`autoRelease` in manual referencing code is outlined in Apple’s [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think. Just follow the Golden Rule: if you said `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain`, you must say `release`. Did you say `alloc`? Yes! Then you must say `release`. You need to `autorelease` your `retVal` before you return it.

Other comments: Do not start a method name with a capital letter. And do not start your function name with `get`! That has an effect on what the analyzer expects the memory management to be.

One last comment: If at all possible use ARC instead of manual memory management.

Comment: `GetNSStringFromUTF16()` is a C function, not a method.

Comment: ... or `new` or `mutableCopy`, too.

Comment: @Rob Yes, in my formulation of the golden rule (the ARC rule, get it? for Alloc, Retain, Copy) `alloc` includes `new` because it is just `alloc-init` and `copy` includes `mutableCopy`.

Comment: And he can simplify with `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:length:encoding:]`